# Ruby - Secret number game, how to get the game to restart?

Tags: ruby

im trying to get my secret number game to work properly.

I'm having issues with getting the game to restart when:

you have no more guesses left
you win the game

I used a while loop, but have troubles accessing it via a function/method..

edit:

so basically players are given 3 attempts to guess the secret number. if they win, they will be asked if they want to restart the game. if they lose, they will also be asked if they want to retry.

here is the code:

thanks in advance guys

```
 def get_input
        gets.chomp
    end

    puts "Welcome to the Secret Number Game! Please tell me your name"
    player_name = get_input
    puts "Welcome #{player_name}!"
    puts "Guess a number between 1 - 10. You only have 3 attempts!"
    secret_number = 1 + rand(10)
    restart = true

    while restart

        def playAgain ( restart )
            puts "Would you like to play again? (y/n)"
            answer = get_input
            if answer == "n"
                restart = false
            end
        end

    def guess_check ( player_input, secret_number )     
        if player_input > secret_number
            puts "Wrong, sorry! Too high!"
        elsif player_input < secret_number
            puts "Wrong, sorry! Too low!" 
        else
            puts "Congratulations, you've guessed the secret number! #{[secret_number]}"
            playAgain ( restart )
        end
    end


        ############################## START GAME ###########################################

        guesses = []
        attempts = 3    

        while attempts

            attempts = attempts - 1
            if attempts == -1
                puts "Sorry, you have no more tries"
                playAgain ( restart )
            else
                puts "Guess the secret number (You have #{attempts} tries left):"
            end

            player_input = get_input.to_i
            guesses.push ( player_input )
            guess_check( player_input, secret_number )
            puts "You've guessed - #{guesses}"

        end

            playAgain ( restart )

    end
```

Answer (score 1):

`0` in ruby is truthy, not falsey, contradictory to most languages. To break a while loop one should explicitly check it’s greater than zero:

```
- while attempts
+ while attempts > 0
```

or, more rubyish:

```
3.downto(0) do |attempts| 
    ...  
end
```

**UPD**

The portion with restarts. You get *local* restart variable defined in `playAgain`. Google for ruby scopes, in short: local variables in functions are not visible out of scope of this function; parameters are passed to the function *by value*. That said, defining `restart = false` inside `playAgain` makes no sence at all, since that local variables dies within the function scope. Possible solution would be to declare an instance variable `@restart`. In this case you won’t need to pass it as parameter. But most reasonable way to get things done would be to return a boolean value from `playAgain`:

```
def playAgain
  puts "Would you like to play again? (y/n)"
  answer = get_input
  answer != "n" # return a boolean from the function in last statement
end
```

And then the whole scope would be looking like:

```
def playAgain
  puts "Would you like to play again? (y/n)"
  answer = get_input
  answer != "n" # return a boolean from the function in last statement
end

def guess_check ( player_input, secret_number )     
  if player_input > secret_number
    puts "Wrong, sorry! Too high!"
  elsif player_input < secret_number
    puts "Wrong, sorry! Too low!" 
  else
    puts "Congratulations! Result: #{secret_number}"
  end
  player_input == secret_number # return true on success
end

# let’s go!
loop do # main loop
  guesses = []
  3.downto(1) |attempts| # 3 attemts
    puts "Guess the secret number (You have #{attempts} tries left):"

    player_input = get_input.to_i
    guesses.push(player_input)
    # you have to return true/false from guess check 
    #     and rerun the topmost loop if success
    # see the trick with logical and below:
    #     on normal execution the loop will return it’s initial
    #     (3 in this particular case)
    #     on successful guess is will break, returning false  
    break false if guess_check(player_input, secret_number)
    puts "You've guessed - #{guesses}"
  end && puts "Sorry, you have no more tries"

  break unless playAgain # will break a topmost loop unless `y` input
end
```

Comment: will give this a try later when im back home from work . so since I want to break the attempt loop when attempts is equal to -1, i should write "- while attempts > -1"? how would this allow me to allow the player to restart the game though after they finish all attempts, or if they win the game? e.g. access the "while = restart" loop

Comment: Would you mind to describe the logic you want to implement in plain English? I just saw `while attempts` which results in an infinite loop and pointed out to that.

Comment: haha sorry. i shouldve explained. So the steps would be 1) Ask player what their name is. 2) Tell players to guess a number from 1 to 10 3) they only have 3 tries to guess 4) if they guessed wrong 3 times, the player will be asked if they want to restart the game 5) if they guessed right, they will also be asked if they want to restart. my issue is getting the "restart" portion to run.